# Time complexity of DFS on graph (O(V+E)) vs DFS on matrix (3^(M*N))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, depth-first-search, backtracking

Apologies if it sounds too illogical.

While solving some of the competitive questions today, a weird thought came across my mind.

We say time complexity of DFS is O(V+E) because we traverse the adjacency list only once i.e for every node we consider its edges.

However when performing dfs on matrix of size M*N.
A matrix we can say, is a graph with M*N vertices (every cell is a vertex) and there is an edge to its neighbouring cell ==> every vertex have 4 edges (lets ignore border cases for simplicity)

Then while we do DFS

```
    private void dfs(int grid[][], int i, int j, int m, int n) {
        if(i<0 || j<0 || i>m || j>n || visited[i][j])
            return;
        visited[i][j] = true;
        dfs(grid, i+1, j, m, n);
        dfs(grid, i-1, j, m, n);
        dfs(grid, i, j-1, m, n);
        dfs(grid, i, j+1, m, n)
        visited[i][j] = false;
    }
```

==> in graph terminology its O(V+E) => O(M*N + 4*M*N) => O(5M*N) => O(M*N)
==> But time complexity is 4^(M*N)

Where does this analogy goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of O(V+E) holds good only if each node is visited once. In your code you visit a node and mark it as visited but after parent is done, you are marking it as not visited.

So when the next child is processed, it will visit its parent again. If a parent has 4 children it will be visited by its children 1 extra time, making it 4 visits for each node and complexity is 4x4x...(MN) = 4^MN.

You remove `visited[i][j] = false`, and you will see that a node once visited is never visited again and complexity is O(number of nodes) = O(MN)

Comment: The node at (i, j) isn't immediately revisited by its own children -- `visited[i][j]` is still `true` at that time, so the recursive call that attempts to do so returns immediately. But it will be visited again later *many times* by paths from the start vertex that have not yet visited its own parent. 3^(M\*N) upper-bounds the number of configurations, but each configuration takes between 1 and M\*N steps to be generated.

Comment: Thank you @SomeDude for your answer

Comment: @SomeDude Its 3^(M*N) precisely and not 4^(M*N) because out of the four recursion we do, 1 always results in base condition because its already visited (Hence constant time for this recursion).

Therefore for every single cell, we effectively make 3 recursion calls

Comment: shouldn't the time complexity be O((n + m)!/(n!m!))? Because we are potentially visiting every unique path in grid (due to visited check)??